# AngularJs - element.on('submit') is not working in my directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, submit

I am attempting to use an ng-submit call to fire a submit event to my custom directive, but it isn't firing.

Here is a plunk that illustrates my problem.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <form name="loginForm" ng-submit="login()" novalidate="">
        <input type="submit" class='please-wait' value="Submit Me" />
    </form>
</div>
```

js code:

```
app.directive('pleaseWait', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "C",
        compile: function (element) {
            element.on('submit', function (e) {
                alert('Submit called');
            });

            element.on('click', function (e) {
                alert('Click called');
            });
        }
    };
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/lwHPVJI75q8bvVoSX1WP?p=preview

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `submit` is an event of form, not input

Comment: Moving the class please-wait to the form fixed it.

Comment: re-post as answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"submit" is not an event on the `input` element but is an event on the `form` so the directive is listening for an event it won't receive.